# Can anybody explain about phase shift and phase spectrum terms in case of multidimensional signal?

Tags: optics, waves, terminology, spectroscopy, signal-processing

I know about [phase of a 1D signal](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/phase), but when I move into higher dimensions like 2D or 3D etc, it becomes headache to grasp the concept.

What do the terms "phase shift" and "phase spectrum" mean in case of multidimensional (2D, 3D etc.) signal like an Image or video signal? How do we analyze phase spectrum? Which information do we get from phase spectrum about the signal? Can anybody explain with a plot or example?